# How to refine the output of DiscretizeRegion & ImplicitRegion?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

This code

```
DiscretizeRegion[
ImplicitRegion[y/(0.2*Max[x,z]) >= Max[x,z]/Abs[x-z] && y/(0.9*Max[x,z]) <= Max[x,z]/Abs[x-z] && 
x + y + z == 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.01}, Method -> "ContourPlot3D", PlotTheme -> "DarkMesh"]
```

produces the graph below, whose lower tails are chopped.

Could it be refined somehow so that the full graph is shown?

[image]

Comment: Appears chopped because of the limits imposed on region.  Try adding options to the plot:  Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful.